# ScrollTo doesn't work

Tags: jquery, scrollto, easing

I re-open my previous question as it has been closed due to not beinig specific enough.

I'm trying to make jQuery plugin "ScrollTo" work, but I'm definitively doing something wrong despite using the same method that the doc describes.

Here is how I proceed :

Calling jquery at the end of my `<head>`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/init.js'></script>
```

I put the code in my menu link

```
<li><a title="$(...).scrollTo( 'home' );" href="#home"><span></span>Home</a></li>
```

which is how they seems to have been doing in the doc : view-source:http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

However it doesn't work. Am I missing something there?

Comment: Setting `title` to some code won't do anything good. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you have in js/init.js file?

Comment: @JanDvorak Actually the `scrollTo` plugin appears to make use of the code in the `title` attribute, so while you'd ordinarily be right I think not in this case...

Comment: @MattB. does it? Why does it seem like a bad idea, given the purpose of `title` and given the fact that it's actually `eval`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, it's probably not the best plugin design but a lot of jQuery plugins used to use the `title` attribute before HTML5 `data-` attributes came along (although even without that I think a better approach would be possible)...so sometimes you just have to deal with weirdly-designed plugins.

Comment: @MattB. I hope the code is there just to make it visible on hover - not to be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, here is what my init.js contain http://hine.be/js/init.js

Comment: @MattB. the `title` was indeed just presentational. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In the demo

```
<a title="$(...).scrollTo( 'home' );" href="#home">
```

the `title` attribute is, indeed, used for its original purpose, and for that purpose only. The purpose is to show a small tooltip on hover. This title is in no way interpreted by the plugin.

The behavior is coded in *their* `js/init.js` file, and it looks like this:

```
$('#relative-selector').click(function()
  $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo( 'li:eq(14)', 800 );
});
...
//the same for every link on the page
```

#### The correct usage

is described on the main project page, and the page doesn't mention the `title` attribute at all. The purpose of the demo is to show what's possible with the plugin, and it doesn't seem to be designed for source code inspection. The main page URL is:
 http://flesler.blogspot.cz/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

In your case, add an ID (or a class) to the link so that you can find it from Javascript. Then add a click handler to the link, that will call the plugin. If you pass a string to `scrollTo`, it should be a selector instead of an ID (add `#`). To scroll the browser window, use `scrollTo` as `$.scrollTo`, to scroll any other container, use `$(container).scrollTo`. Also, you may remove the `href` target.

example HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="click-me">...</a>
```

example JS:

```
$("#click-me").click(function(){
  $.scrollTo("#home");
});
```

Remember to wrap in `$(document).ready(...)` if you like your scripts in the `<head>`. Also note that `init.js` is the name of the *demo* main JS file. If yours is named otherwise, you don't need an `init.js` file, and you certainly don't need to copy/paste the one from the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that prepending a hash sign to 'home' may fix the issue:

```
<li><a title="$(...).scrollTo( '#home' );" href="#home"><span></span>Home</a></li>
```

It seems that `scrollTo` expects a jQuery selector (for what it seems you want), so you need the hash sign to make it a valid selector.

Comment: See my answer. The hash was only a part of the problem.